# PDO conection fail on real server PDO->__construct / LINUX vs WINDOWS servers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

so yes I just uploaded a web site and the conection to the database is not good, using WampServer it works very well.

This is my error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in E:\kunden\homepages\16\d634736285\www\compras\index.php:114 Stack trace: #0 E:\kunden\homepages\16\d634736285\www\compras\index.php(114): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=db63...', 'databName', 'Pass', Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\kunden\homepages\16\d634736285\www\compras\index.php on line 114

And this is the code on line 114:

```
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=dHOSTName;dbname=DatabaName', 'User', 'pass', $pdo_options);
```

**I have seen other post like this one but no one solve my answer!**

Thank you

Comment: Does your host provide `PDO`? They must have it enabled for you to use...

Comment: did you make sure a simple page with `phpinfo();` shows PDO ready to go?

Comment: hmm I dont know I hope they do let me see

Comment: @Drew should just put phpinfo(); in a page? to see eaht it says?

Comment: yeah and scroll down and read the blocks of what modules are in use

Comment: @Drew Can you take a look? lacajota.com

Comment: doesn't look terribly promising

Comment: @Boris, if you ctrl+f for `pdo`, you see that for `PDO drivers`, there is `no value`

Comment: @FirstOne tahnk you! And what should I do?

Comment: checking it out, https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=21009, not sure, can you do it cuz it is the hoster?

Comment: You'll have to ask for the people that manage your host to install it for you (if possible). If it's not possible, you'll have to either switch hosts or your code. In case you are managing it yourself, take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) -> Installation part (Or just google how to do it for your specif case)

Comment: Ok i see, tahnk you @Drew

Comment: thank you @FirstOne

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer for my question but if you have this issue too, make sure your website is a Linux server. In my case I had to contact the services of my hosting to migrate from a Windows server to a Linux server.

So this is what I learn:

**Windows servers :**

Facilitates management of content and graphic conception.
If you work with Microsoft apps like ASP you should take this option too. And For hark seach functions.

**Linux servers:**

Reputed to be stable and secure, this kind of server works better with PHP, Perl and MySQL. Perfect for e-commerce web sites and Linux servers are much more cheaper.